# Where can I read CS papers?

Tags: research

I am a self taught programmer, with no formal degree in CS. I have read couple of papers which were recommended on some or other blog and found them interesting. Where can I read papers on computer science ? Are these papers available for free?
If not papers are there any essays on any popular blog posts?

Comment: You could use arXiv, sciencedirect, or even a post in SE http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read for more, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=computer+science+papers

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think this is better, no?

Comment: Better, but lmgtfy is still pretty gratuitous compared to "for more, use a search engine."

Comment: @cagirici I can google, but people like me come here because it isn't always direct answers to your questions, but at time guidance and constructive suggestions from competent users, to find answers to one's queries. Thank you

Comment: What about CS interests you? Algorithms? Languages? Type Systems? Formal methods? Automatas? Computability in general? Something else?  Depending on what you are interested we could suggest a very different set of sources.

Comment: @Sandbox why not share which papers you already read and found interesting too?

Comment: Since [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/) is pretty much the answer, I'll close this as "too broad". If you have specific issues with accessing individual papers, you can hit [chat]. Note that for issues with *working* as a scientist (even if you don't identify yourself in that way, reading scientific articles *is* part of doing science!) there is [academia.SE].

Comment: Note that there are many thousands of papers. It's impossible to read all, and it can be very hard to find good ones. I recommend you talk to people working in the areas that interest you and ask them to recommend their favorite articles to you. Start there, following references (in both directions!).

Comment: @jimmycarr - http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/steele.pdf and https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/papers/objects-essay.pdf

Comment: @Bakuriu I wasn't interested in any specific topic, but look at my above comment and you will know I just came across these two papers and read them. It isn't that I understood everything, but I found them interesting and readable.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no formal degree in CS, I think what you need is textbook instead of scientific papers.

Being a self-taught programmer is a great achievement and I think you can build up on that with theory. But, reading papers require some deep knowledge in some area.

I would suggest you to buy one of these books:

[Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/)

[Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)

[Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++, 4th Edition
Mark A. Weiss](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Weiss-Data-Structures-and-Algorithm-Analysis-in-C-4th-Edition/PGM148299.html)

In these books, you can also find some references to suggested readings.

Comment: thanks. I have read Data Structures: A Pseudocode Approach with 
Gilberg and Data Structures Using C and C++ by Tanenbaum. The first one was pretty easy read, the second one was a bit tough for me.

Comment: @Sandbox yes, this is what I mean. You might need to cover very basics of algorithms (i.e. introduction) in order to go deeper and read recent papers.

Comment: "If you have no formal degree in CS, I think what you need is textbook instead of scientific papers." -- citation needed.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been noted, papers probably are not the best way for you to start.

Perhaps you might like to check out the [ArsDigita University website](http://aduni.org/courses/). This has been a project running in 2000 and 2001 (yes, some time has passed since then, but I think this does not really matter for the basics of CS), providing an intensive introduction to the most fundamental areas of CS. Course materials are available at the website, as well as pointers to books used in particular courses. In addition, [lecture videos](http://adunivids.neocities.org/) are also available online.

Answer (score 1):

i´m in your same situation. I've never studied computational complexity formally, apart from some programming courses i did.

CS is a very big area of study and the advice people will give you will depend in your particular interests.

An area of study that doesn´t require (in general) to know much about mathematics/complexity theory is the study of the complexity of games. I've beeen reading papers about it and some them are more accesible than others, but generally patience is the most important thing to understand those papers.

A good place to start is the page of wikipedia: [List of np complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems/). Look in the section of games and puzzles and you will see references to papers about game complexity

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on reading papers, you should be able to browse the journals in the library of a university with a CS program (the more engineering-oriented the university, the more likely they will have such papers).  As long as you are discreet and don't try to take out anything, you shouldn't even need to be a student or faculty to use the library (I've done this myself).

On the other hand, don't be surprised when what you read turns out to be both (a) very challenging to understand and (b) concerned with issues far outside the range of practical significance.

Comment: That depends very much on the library in question. They're not necessarily physically accessible to the public.